# Add border on mouseover and remove border on mouseout

Tags: javascript, html

I'm really new to Javascript and I have a work that asks me "onmouseover adds a border to the ordered list, AND onmouseout removes the border", it is wanted to be over a button. I have no idea how to do that and I really need some help, also, the lame part is that it **must** be in Javascript and non other coding languages. 
So far I got the most simplistic thing ever :/

```
<script>
// Border
function border() {
}

</script>
```

and

```
<div> 
<button type="button" id="b1" class="button" onmouseover="border()">Button 1</button>

</div>
```

I'm not sure how to do that, if I could get any help would be appreciated! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The code in [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover) will help you.

Basically, you need to listen on the `onmouseover` event to add the border and the `onmouseout` event to remove it. I hope this helps :)